Heronian Triangles with side 3 - How to find.
I know from a list that triangles of sides 3,4,5  3,25,26 and 3,148,149 are Heronian, but haven't so far been able to spot any obvious mathematical relationship which would gave a clue to finding the next such triangle of shortest side 3.
Can anyone help? I apologise in advance if I am missing something obvious

Have a look at https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/8-5/carlson-a.pdf around $(6)$

All small solutions $3, m,n$ (with $\max(m,n)\le 25$ for instance) can be found by a finite quick computer search. Assume now that the maximal side is bigger than $25$. Then the sides $3,m,n$ are of the shape:

either $3,m,m+0$, case (A),
or $3,m,m+1$, case (B),
or $3,m,m+2$, case (C),

where $m\ge 25$ is an integer. We may want to introduce $k=0,1,2$ so that the bigger side is $m+k$.
The area $A$ is given by Heron's formula
$$
16A^2=(2m+3+k)(2m-3+k)(3+k)(3-k)\ .
$$
The L.H.S. above is always even.
In cases (A), (C) we have $k=0,2$ even, so all factors on the R.H.S. are odd, a contradiction. So only case (B), $k=1$, works. Then we have successively
$$
\begin{aligned}
16A^2 &=(2m+4)(2m-2)(4)(2)\ ,\\
2A^2 &=(2m+4)(2m-2)\ ,\\
2A^2 &=(4m^2+4m+1)-9\ ,\\
9 &= (2m+1)^2-2A^2\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This is a (not normed) Pell equation, $9=x^2-2y^2$, and it is clear that any $x$ that verifies is odd, and leads to a solution. The general solution $(x,y)$ is obtained from a special solution ($(x_0,y_0)=(9,6)$ for instance) of this not normed equation, and a general solution of the associated (standard) Pell equation. It is convenient to associate to each solution the number
$$
z = x+y\sqrt 2\ ,
$$
then the general solution is
$$
z_n= x + y\sqrt 2=(9+6\sqrt 2)(3+2\sqrt 2)^n\ ,\qquad\text{ $n$ integer number.}
$$

So we compute with bare hands in the small cases:
$$
\begin{aligned}
z_0 &= 9+6\sqrt 2\ ,& 9&=2m+1\ ,&m&=4\ ,\\
z_1 &= (9+6\sqrt 2)(3+2\sqrt2)
\\
&=51 + 36\sqrt 2
\ ,& 51&=2m+1\ ,&m&=25\ ,
\\
z_2 &= (9+6\sqrt 2)(3+2\sqrt2)^2
\\
&=297 + 210\sqrt 2
\ ,& 297&=2m+1\ ,&m&=148\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
these $m$-values are also mention by OP,
and the next values are as follows...
$$
\begin{aligned}
z_3 &= (9+6\sqrt 2)(3+2\sqrt2)^3 =1731 + 1224\sqrt 2\ ,& m&=865\ ,\\
z_4 &= (9+6\sqrt 2)(3+2\sqrt2)^4 =10089 + 7134\sqrt 2\ ,& m&=5044\ ,\\
z_5 &= (9+6\sqrt 2)(3+2\sqrt2)^5 =58803 + 41580\sqrt 2\ ,& m&=29401\ ,\\
z_6 &= (9+6\sqrt 2)(3+2\sqrt2)^6 =342729 + 242346\sqrt 2\ ,& m&=171364\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and so on.

Check for the last case: The sides are $a,b,c=3,\ 171364,\ 171365$, the half-perimeter is $p=\frac 12(a+b+c)=171366=2\cdot 3\cdot 13^4$, and we compute furthermore $p-a=171363=3\cdot 239^2$, $p-b=2$, $p-c=1$, so the area is:
$$
A=\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}
=  2\cdot 3\cdot 13^2\cdot 239=242346\ ,
$$
which is the component in $\sqrt 2$ in $z_6$.

Many thanks to Dann Jules for his reply, and apologies if I've used the wrong forum.
